# Button Onclick EventHandler from CreateChildControls

Tags: web-part, development, web

I have declared a button in my CreateChildControls method in my web part page:

```
TableCell updateCell = new TableCell();
        Update = new Button();
        Update.Text = "Update";
        Update.OnClientClick += new EventHandler(Update_OnClick);
        updateCell.Controls.Add(Update);
        ButtonRow.Controls.Add(updateCell);
```

This is the eventhandler that I created:

```
    private void Update_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_TYPE == "FIXED")
        {
            Item["Retail"] = txtFixedRetail.Text;
            Item.Update();
            EmailFixedAlert();
        }
    }
```

However JScript throws an error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined
```

And produces this in the HTML:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="ctl00$m$g_c260f907_31c1_436b_b99e_9bf79427625c$ctl11"     value="Update" onclick="System.EventHandler;" /></td>
```

Why is the eventhandler that I declared in the WebPart not passing to the Page?
Do I have to push all events to the Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Button.OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is assigning JavaScript to run in the browser

[Button.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.90%29) is for Server side event handling